# Return current path of PowerBI Workbook

Tags: powerbi, m

Is there a way in a PowerBI Query to return the path of the workbook?

I am looking to create an environment variable that detects whether I am working on the file locally or if it has been deployed to the powerbi.com website.

Comment: Are you referring to an Excel Workbook or a Power BI Desktop PBIX file?

Comment: In this case I am in a .pbix but ideally I'd like a solution that I can use in either/or (as I tend to copy and paste a lot of M Code).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a direct way to do this. You might try using the Folder source and see what the difference in result is when you run a refresh in the service (it could be disabled, btw) vs. when you run it on the desktop.

Could you also tell us why you'd like to know this?  I'm sure there's a specific problem or scenario you're trying to solve for and maybe there's another way to solve it if not using the technique you're asking about in this question.

Comment: I'm considering creating seed data that reflects the structure of our live environment on sql server but has less data. Currently I filter for last months sales and then delete the filter before I push to the powerbi website.

Comment: I'd liked to do this dynamically based on whether I am working in my development environment or my production environment (based on where the file is located).

Comment: And sorry, the specific problem is just making the powerbi desktop perform faster. Mainly caused by so much data coming down from the SQL Server. Also how would I find the 'folder source'??